# Rotate objects in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, transform

I'm trying to rotate rectangles according to some data. With, the following code, the rotation applies to the whole line. How can I get each "rect" to have his own rotation applied, keeping them on the same line?

```
let canevas = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 1000);

let rectangles = d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data([10, 20, 30, 40])
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", (d, i) => (i * 30) + 30)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("transform", (d) => `rotate(${d})`);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the normal behaviour of `rotate`, since the `rotate` function of the `translate` attribute rotates the elements around the origin of the coordinates system (0,0).

An easy solution is setting the positions in the same translate:

```js
let canevas = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width",300)
   .attr("height",100);

let rectangles = d3.select("svg")
   .selectAll("rect")
   .data([10,20,30,40])
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("width",20)
   .attr("height",20)
   .attr("transform", (d,i) => `translate(${(i*30)+30},30) rotate(${d})`);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```